# This bevel modifier is acting weird looking for solutions

Tags: modeling, modifiers

ok so I'm using the bevel modifier to bevel all edges in a weight group and 95% of them work but some of them aren't, pic1 there is a gap plus not beveled, pic 2 it just stopped mid way.
[Blend file if needed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sIDr1HZuar7O9uHn1wZMo4nQZrSFYBWJ/view)
[image]

[image]

Lmk if need something else

Comment: Hello, it's caused by your topology, but your link asks for an authorization

Comment: I think the vital detail is probably your topology. It would help to show the wire frame in medium-close-up on a problematic area.

Comment: how do i fix the link?

Comment: I can't download your file, it shows no permission.

Comment: use https://pasteall.org/blend/ upload your file and copy paste the URL it will generate